# Are Wi-Fi 'transparent' buildings superior to antennas mounted on the exterior?

Tags: interference, digital-communications

Looking in particular at wireless mesh networks in cities - is it advantageous to design a building that does not interfere with Wi-Fi (e.g. out of wood instead of steel and concrete), or would placing an antenna on the roof/facade resolve the problem?

I appreciate this is quite open ended, I'm an architect running a design project looking at hertzian space, (the spatial quality of e.m. waves) and without sufficient technical knowledge I'm struggling to progress beyond this question.

Answer (score 4):

#### "Wi-Fi" friendly?

As with any engineering task, you must first precisely define your objectives.

In your case, to be "Wi-Fi" friendly probably means that the users of your space get a consistent and "fast" connection to the Internet (or other network resource). Bandwidth (communication capacity) is a shared resource. All users of your space compete for it.

In a high density environment, like a hotel or office, it may actually be *advantageous* to use Wi-Fi absorbing materials. This allows you to reuse the same communication bandwidth in different physical locations.

This is how the cell-phone network works.

[image]

#### Basic concepts

There are really three things a material can do to a Wi-Fi signal:

1. Nothing -- Signal transits without alteration
2. Attenuate -- Signal is absorbed by the material. This prevents (or reduces) communication on the other side of the material.
3. Reflect -- Signal is reflected from the material surface. This prevents communication on the other side.

Real materials do all three in differing combinations.

#### Application

"Wi-Fi," in common usage, refers to the 2.4GHz ISM band of frequencies (there are other Wi-Fi bands, notably near 5GHz). That frequency band is near the natural peak absorption of water.

Accordingly, Wi-Fi will not perform well in moist environments (indoor pool decks, spas, near water pipes, etc). However, absorption is typically fine.

Reflection is the bigger hazard in infrastructure planning because it results in interference. It's like trying to have a conversation in an echo-producing cave. The more you talk (and the more people talking) the harder it is for *anyone* to be understood.

Large flat grounded conductive surfaces (metal, most oil-infused wood, metalized plastics, foils, etc) are the worst offenders in buildings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is important in the design. If WiFi is more important than for example the building robustness and longevity, then yes - build if from wood, paper, whatever (btw, the most fabrics are pretty radio transparent).

If the important properties of the building is to be long lasting, robust and not to fall on the first storm, then build it this way and if as a result it is not WiFi friendly, it is not a big deal - the sysadmins will put an access point in every room if needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

In short don't compromise on the building design. The technical guys on radio comms should be consulted on WiFi infrastructure and appropriate ducting and facilities designed in at an early stage.